# Can I build the test code automatically calling the abcclientproxy.cpp methods, Generated by gSOAP 2.8.16 from abc.h

Tags: c++, wsdl, gsoap

I am facing issues calling the methods of `abcclientproxy.cpp`, this  `abcclientproxy.cpp` is Generated by gSOAP 2.8.16 from abc.h which was inturn generated by the `abc.wsdl` file.

SO I wanted to know if gSoap generates a test client.cpp(main) or server.cpp code which calls the methods of `abcclientproxy.cpp`.

I follow the below

> wsdl2h.exe -s -o abc.h abc.wsdl
>
> soapcpp2.exe -2 -i -Iimport abc.h
> also tried
> soapcpp2.exe -2 -i -j -y -Iimport abc.h

Answer (score 1):

From *9.15 Generating an Auto Test Server for Client Testing* chapter of soapdoc2.pdf of gSOAP 2.8.16 tool:

> The soapcpp2 -T option generates an auto-test server application in soapTester.cpp,which is to be compiled and linked with the code generated for a server 
>   implementation, i.e. soapServer.cpp (or with the generated server object class) and soapC.cpp.